Ubuntu 24.04 stopped starting docked with lid closed vs 22.04
I explained all here https://ubuntu-mate.community/t/ubuntu-mate-24-04-6-8-0-41-generic-dell-m4800-docking-station-wont-start/28133/4 but now their website is down.
So, I have a precision m4800 which I use docked with 2 external monitors. I was fool enough to upgrade from 22.04 to 24.04 and now I have this problem.
The laptop does not start with the lid closed anymore. I hear the login sound , without seeing the login form on the external monitors, then I enter the password and hit enter and them black screens everywhere... I have to long press power button to shutdown and open the lid to be able to start the laptop.
The grub is seen in the external monitors.
Meanwhile I tried some tweaks with no luck based on:
https://www.reddit.com/r/gnome/comments/91yezn/using_the_laptop_with_closed_lid_when_docked/?rdt=56710
https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1517967
https://superuser.com/questions/1605504/etc-systemd-logind-conf-is-being-ignored
sudo pluma /etc/systemd/logind.conf
DEFAULS:
#HandleLidSwitch=suspend
#HandleLidSwitchExternalPower=suspend
#HandleLidSwitchDocked=ignore
#PowerKeyIgnoreInhibited=no
#SuspendKeyIgnoreInhibited=no
#HibernateKeyIgnoreInhibited=no
#LidSwitchIgnoreInhibited=yes

1st try
#HandleLidSwitch=suspend
#HandleLidSwitchExternalPower=suspend
HandleLidSwitchDocked=ignore
#PowerKeyIgnoreInhibited=no
#SuspendKeyIgnoreInhibited=no
#HibernateKeyIgnoreInhibited=no
#LidSwitchIgnoreInhibited=yes

2nd try
#HandleLidSwitch=suspend
#HandleLidSwitchExternalPower=suspend
HandleLidSwitchDocked=ignore
#PowerKeyIgnoreInhibited=no
#SuspendKeyIgnoreInhibited=no
#HibernateKeyIgnoreInhibited=no
LidSwitchIgnoreInhibited=no

no luck...

You state the Ubuntu-MATE discourse was down; yes it was for near ~two hours, but the connection with CloudFlare has been fixed & its fully functional again.

Yes it is now. Anyway maybe it is not a mate issue but an Ubuntu issue.

It started working again with 6.8.0-51-generic Ubuntu 24.04.1 LTS
But after each update I see it not working then working again...
